# Macbook Pro shutting down on its own after sleep

Tags: macos, shutdown, sleep, macbook-pro, osx-yosemite

My Macbook Pro 2013 (upgraded from Mavericks to Yosemite) keeps shutting down on its own after I put it to sleep by closing the lid. It used to be that this happened a few hours after I closed it--usually 2-3 hours--but I think now it's happening much sooner, sometimes within an hour of putting the lid down.

Another problem that may/may not be related is that after I login, the progress bar will only go about halfway and then stop, so it never actually boots up. At the moment I'm trying to solve it by removing all login items but it's too soon to tell if this will work or not. Suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Just to say, I have kind of the same issue. Plus my OSX prompt's that I should change the battery... wtf?